# Is it discouragement when a person hears bad news and thinks so I will have to live with this hardship until next year?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Was I discouraged when I heard bad news and I said so I will have to live with this hardship until next year?

Comment: Bad news is often discouraging, but that depends on the individual. A truly discouraged person might say 'I want to die now!'.

Comment: You *might* be "discouraged" in the cited context, but not necessarily. To be honest, I think saying *So I will have to live with this hardship until next year* rather suggests [***stoic resignation***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stoic+resignation%22), which in some ways is the *opposite* of being discouraged / disheartened / demoralized.

Comment: what if the bad news makes you feel down and disturbed?

Comment: @JimiA Have you looked up "discouraged" in a dictionary? If so, what are you still unsure about?

Comment: It's rather [**resignation**](https://psychology-spot.com/resignation-meaning-acceptance/), i.e. "the acceptance of something undesirable but inevitable."